# Isolation Forest Length of values does not match length of index

Tags: python, pandas, csv, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I was running isolation forest trying to apply it on a 10049972 rows x 19 columns database, but after 2 hours of running I got the following error. I really don't understand why did I get it, nor how do I resolve it?

Code:

```
 import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest


df = pd.read_csv('D:\\Project\\database\\4-Final\\Final After.csv',low_memory=True)


iForest = IsolationForest(behaviour='new', n_estimators=80,  contamination='auto' , max_samples=150)


df['anomaly'] = iForest.fit_predict(df.values.reshape(-1,1))


df=df.drop(df['anomaly'==-1],inplace=True)

df.to_csv('D:\\Project\\database\\4-Final\\IF TEST.csv', index=False)
```

and the error is:

```
 ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-fc55c8b1f328> in <module>
     16 
     17 
---> 18 df['anomaly'] = iForest.fit_predict(df.values.reshape(-1,1))
     19 
     20 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   3368         else:
   3369             # set column
-> 3370             self._set_item(key, value)
   3371 
   3372     def _setitem_slice(self, key, value):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   3443 
   3444         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
-> 3445         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
   3446         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   3447 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _sanitize_column(self, key, value, broadcast)
   3628 
   3629             # turn me into an ndarray
-> 3630             value = sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)
   3631             if not isinstance(value, (np.ndarray, Index)):
   3632                 if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) > 0:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in sanitize_index(data, index, copy)
    517 
    518     if len(data) != len(index):
--> 519         raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of index')
    520 
    521     if isinstance(data, ABCIndexClass) and not copy:

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be with

`df.values.reshape(-1,1)`

Look at this example

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(.2, .3), (.0, .6), (.6, .0), (.2, .1)], columns=['dogs', 'cats'])

df
   dogs  cats
0   0.2   0.3
1   0.0   0.6
2   0.6   0.0
3   0.2   0.1

df.values.reshape(-1,1)
array([[0.2],
       [0.3],
       [0. ],
       [0.6],
       [0.6],
       [0. ],
       [0.2],
       [0.1]])
```

So you end up providing a `shape (n_samples*n_feature, 1)` vector to the `fit_predict` and you are plugging back the resulting `shape (n_samples*n_feature,)` as a column to a `df` with `shape (n_samples,n_feature)`. There's a mismatch between the number of rows.

Comment: So what I'm doing is wrong? So what I'm doing is combining all 19 columns into 1 and applying isolation forest? So to apply isolation forest on each column individually I need to separate them and apply isolation forest on each column one by one?

Comment: Why do you need to combine the columns? Isolationforest will return the anomaly score of each sample (rows) based on the input features (columns). You can get more info in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html)
Just do `df['anomaly'] = iForest.fit_predict(df)`

Comment: So after using df['anomaly'] = iForest.fit_predict(df) , I get the following error, for the line `df=df.drop(df['anomaly'==-1],inplace=True`), the error is `KeyError: False`. Should I change it to `df=df.drop(df['anomaly'==-1].index,inplace=True`) ?

Comment: There's no syntax like `df['anomaly'==-1]`, I'd do something like `df = df[df['anomaly'] != -1]`